# How do I gather data from various requests using rxjs in angular in a non-hideous way?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My use-case is as simple as I would think its ubiquitous, yet I cannot find a single tutorial that explains it decently.

I want to fetch a variety of data in the onInit() of my angular module, some sequential, some concurrent.
Once all that is done I need to perform syncronous operations on the collected data.
I want my code to be halfway readable.

Suppose I have the following (all observables return once, no actual streams):

- 1) An observable routing parameter to get an Id from
- 2) A request to get my main entity using that Id (sequential)
- 3) Three requests to different endpoints to get additional data, using id's retrieved from the second point (sequential to point 2, but can run concurrent to each other)

I simply want to get all that data, pack it in one single observable, subscribe to that so I can run my actual operation in that subscriptions callback.

What I am looking for: A simple pseudocode / code structure that tells me which operators to put in which sequence. Bonus points for the "why".

> $Obs1.pipe(mergemap(...))

Extra bonus for readability, if Rxjs is at all compatible with clean code. Yes, I am frustrated by my inability to grasp this, and the utter lack of examples on the matter.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Operator Decision Tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree)?

Comment: Yes, that does not answer my question as there is no single operator that solves my barely-above-trivial complexity issue. I expect I will need 2-3 Operators in conjunction, though I can't line them up in a way that satisfies my requirements.

Comment: No, there is no single operator, but you can create your own operator based on the existing one. Then the call will be just one. Your problem can be seen in the forkJoin: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin docs.

Comment: I am aware that rxjs works by combining operators. The decision tree does not help me with my question, else I would not have posed it.

Forkjoin only does 3) and I have not been able to combine it with others in a way that satisfies my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
requestRest(data1) {
  // parallel request logic encapsulated in a function
  return forkJoin(
    this.req2(data1),
    this.req3(data1),
    this.req4(data1)
  );
}

ngOnInit() {
  // store id observable in a reusable variable (just to illustrate concept)
  const id$ = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(p => p['id'])
  );

  id$.pipe(
    // switch off id into req1
    switchMap(id => this.req1(id)),
    // switch off req1 into rest of data
    switchMap(data1 => this.requestRest(data1).pipe(
      // inner map to combine data1 with rest of data
      map(restOfData => [data1, ...restOfData])))
  ).subscribe(
     ([d1, d2, d3, d4]) => console.log("got all the data")
  )
}
```

rxjs is a powerful library for building pipelines for handling streams of data.  you can build and compose different pipelines however you see fit. There is a bit of a learning curve but once you get over it, you can handle any data stream you can think of. Every front end event(http requests, websocekts, form inputs, timeouts, intervals, clicks, mousemoves, etc) is a data stream and that's makes rxjs a very valuable tool to learn.

this is kind of a trivial example as far as rxjs streams go as sequential and parallel execution and transforms are the basics. When you consider things like error handling, retry logic, caching, and others, which are things most production applications will want, it gets even more powerful.

`switchMap` alone is one of the most powerful tools offered by rxjs as it handles canceling logic if the id parameter were to change while your requests were in flight, guaranteeing you get the results from the correct id and aren't risking bugs from race conditions between requests.

Comment: Accepted though not yet tested.
This looks like what I was missing, with the doubled switchmap and additional pipe -> map to combine the base entity with the restOfData.

Bonus for the excluding out into a function, thats nice.

That said, being aware of the power is nice, its still massivly counterintuitive and frankly ugly to need this many operators to achive such a simple logic.
Not a criticism of you, and probably based in my lack of familiarity.

Comment: is it though? this is simple as far as rxjs goes, but in general, the logic here is complex. how could it be made prettier with other asynchronous event handling systems? promises? async/await? callbacks? IMO rxjs produces the prettiest code for handling these sorts of events

Comment: The logic here really is just [(x&y&z) after b after a].
The doubling of switchMap is weird to me, why is it not a single operator with n arguments like forkJoin?

I was looking for a stock operator that allows me to a) chain requests and b) get the latest emission from each request. Something I would think would be about the most common operations, what with rest being a thing.

I personally would find promises much easier to read, though I will grant that thats a cheap shot because rxjs does streams and here is used for one-shot events.
Which might be the source of my frustrations.

Comment: such an operator could be built, but probably makes too many implicit assumptions about how you want to handle your sequence logic to be very useful IMO.  the `pipe` operator IS you building your sequence. the `switchMap` operators are you defining how to handle the different phases of the sequence. I think you just need to get used to the syntax and you'll start to appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here could be one approach:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.queryParamMap
    .pipe(
      map(getYourId),
      exhaustMap(
        entityId => this.http.get(/* ... */).pipe(
          exhaustMap( // `entityId` also available here
            results => forkJoin([
              of(results),
              this.http.get(''), // Request 1
              this.http.get(''), // Request 2
              this.http.get(''), // Request 3
            ])
          )
        )
      ),
    )
    .subscribe()
}
```

`exhaustMap` can have only one active inner observable and if an outer value comes in, it will be skipped. Everything is skipped until the current inner observable **completes**.

In this case, I wouldn't say it matters which one of `exhaustMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `switchMap` you use.

The first `exhaustMap` simply makes the request and the next `exhaustMap` will subscribe to an inner observable created based on the data that comes from the first one(`results`).

`forkJoin` will subscribe to its provided observables concurrently, but you're only getting an array of their responses after each observable has **emitted** **at least once** and **completed**.

Comment: Points for looking good and some explanation.
Sadly this does not satisfy one of the requirements, that being that I need the entity **as well as** the three derivative requests in the final observable.

I would expect this to be possible, after all, I already have it right here, after the first "exhaust map", right? The current solution throws away the entity and leaves me with the forkJoin of the ancillary data.
Probably just me badly formulating my requirements, sorry, not a native speaker.

Comment: `exhaustMap` is almost certainly the wrong operator here. if the router params change while the request is in flight, that will be missed. any of the other high order maps would work. exhaustMap is the only one that would break functionality. `switchMap` is probably the best choice though, as it does canceling. `mergeMap` would introduce race conditions and `concatMap` would finish things it doesn't have to finish.

Comment: @bryan60 I totally agree, but the OP can change this if it satisfies his requirements. Since he didn’t mention anything upfront, I decided to follow this approach

Comment: `exhaustMap` is almost never the correct operator. it's almost always `switchMap`... why would you pick `exhaustMap`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ewi2gy

I know the learning curve is steep but sometimes is better to struggle a bit in order to learn properly, getting the answer working exactly as you want will not help in the long run.

```js
import { forkJoin, of, timer, Observable } from "rxjs";
import Axios from "axios-observable";
import { mapTo, switchMap, map, tap, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

interface Post {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Comment {
  id: number;
  body: string;
  postId: number;
}

interface Profile {
  name: string;
}

interface FullPost {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  comments: Comment[];
  profile: string;
}

// this observable gives you the id, assuming from query parameter
const id = of(1);

// then start the stream with that id
const postsObservable = id
  .pipe(
    // map the id to the fetched post
    switchMap((id: number) =>
      Axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts/" + id)
    ),
    // convert response into an object of type Post
    map(response => response.data),
    // fork your requests to get other data, simplistic example only to make the PoC
    mergeMap((post: Post) =>
      forkJoin({
        // get comments
        comments: Axios.get<Comment[]>(
          "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/comments?postId=" +
            post.id
        ),
        // get something else ...
        profile: Axios.get<Profile>(
          "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/profile"
        ),
        // give back also the post as Observable, even more simplistic example
        post: of(post)
      })
    ),
    map(valueObject => {
      // work out the aggregation you got here
      return {
        id: valueObject.post.id,
        title: valueObject.post.title,
        comments: valueObject.comments.data,
        profile: valueObject.profile.data.name,
       } as FullPost;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(fullPost =>  console.log(fullPost));
```

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but this is an issue that has bugged me for a long time and I have recently been involved in implementing a utility operator to explicitly address it. As you say, this is "simple and ubiquitous" and feels like it should have a simple implementation.

With your specific example the code using this operator "concatJoin" looks something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  concatJoin(
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(pluck('id')),
    ([id]) => req1$(id),
    ([,idData]) => forkjoin([req2$(idData), req3$(idData), req4$(idData)]),  
  ).subscribe( 
    ([id, idData, [data2, data3, data4]) => ...
  );
}
```

By default, requests are issued sequentially, with the the results aggregated into an array.  Alternatively the operator allows the use of objects (like forkJoin) and to intermix sequential and parallel requests:

```
ngOnInit() {
  concatJoin(
    {id: this.route.queryParams.pipe(pluck('id'))},
    {idData: ({id}) => req1$(id)},
    {  // requests in the same object are issued in parallel 
      data2: ({idData}) => req2$(idData), 
      data3: ({idData}) => req3$(idData), 
      data4: ({idData}) => req4$(idData),
    }  
  ).subscribe( 
    ({id, idData, data2, data3, data4} => ...
  );
}
```

The operator is available at [rxjs-concat-join](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-concat-join) and the detail is provided in this article [Aggregating Results Across Sequential RxJS Requests](https://thisisuntapped.com/articles/aggregating-rxjs-requests.html).